# How to use LLBLGen with MVC 5

Tags: c#, .net-4.5, asp.net-mvc-5, llblgenpro

Hi This is my Action method

```
public ActionResult Welcome(string name, int numTimes=1)
{
    var customerEntityColl = new EntityCollection(new CustomerEntityFactory());
    var customerEntity = new CustomerEntity(1);
    using(var adapter = new DataAccessAdapter())
    {            
        adapter.FetchEntityCollection(customerEntityColl,null);
    }
    return View(customerEntityColl);            
}
```

and this is my View

```
@model Data.HelperClasses.EntityCollection<Data.EntityClasses.CustomerEntity>

@{
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

@{

}

<p>This is our welcome view and the sender name is @ViewBag.Name and sent @ViewBag.NumTimes times this request</p>

@foreach (var item in Model)
{
    <p>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem=> item.FirstName)</p>
}
```

Now when I run this action method it gives me below error, can somebody please help to fix it..

> The model item passed into the dictionary is of type
>   'Data.HelperClasses.EntityCollection', but this dictionary requires a
>   model item of type
>   'Data.HelperClasses.EntityCollection`1[Data.EntityClasses.CustomerEntity]'.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you're instantiating `EntityCollection`, and not `EntityCollection<CustomerEntity>()` which is what the model expects.

You can just replace `new EntityCollection(new CustomerEntityFactory())` with `new EntityCollection<CustomerEntity>();` (assuming you didn't change any behavior in the CustomerEntityFactory)

Additionally, you should fetch the entity with a Predicate, this is not doing anything at the moment when you're using the adapter model:

```
var customerEntity = new CustomerEntity(1);
```

and this will just fetch all the customers in the database:

```
adapter.FetchEntityCollection(customerEntityColl,null);
```